# Visual Studio 2019 database project incorrectly reporting DATA_COMPRESSION option not supported in Azure SQL

Tags: azure-sql-database, visual-studio-2019, database-project

Using a create table syntax as follows within a Visual Studio 2019 SQL Server Database Project:

```
CREATE TABLE [MyTable]
(
  -- ...
) WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE)
```

I receive the following build error:

> SQL70015: Keyword or statement option 'DATA_COMPRESSION' is not supported for the targeted platform.

However, the `DATA_COMPRESSION` option is supported by Azure SQL Database as indicated by [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-compression/data-compression?view=sql-server-ver15#considerations-for-when-you-use-row-and-page-compression) ("Compression is available in Azure SQL Database") and by the fact that I can manually execute this statement against an Azure SQL Database successfully.

I have configured the target platform to be "Microsoft Azure SQL Database" in the 'Project Settings' tab of the database project's properties page.

The false positive is preventing me from building (and thus deploying) the database project.

Comment: I test the create table syntax in my VS 2019, it works well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the solution was:

1ª - {your project} >> properties >> change the "target plataform" to some thing else, save and build.

2ª - Change back to "Microsoft Azure SQL Database", save and build.

These steps will update the parameter of the project to newest version, in my case was:

From: Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SqlAzureDatabaseSchemaProvider

To:   Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SqlAzureV12DatabaseSchemaProvider